# How to make text type itself in Java? (Android Studio 1.2.2)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm new to JavaScript and am trying to make an app that opens with an animation of text typing itself. This is the JavaScript version of the self-typing text I found in another question:

```
var text = "The quick fox jumped over the lazy dog.";
var charCount = text.length;
var currentLetterCount = 0;
var speed = 100; // How fast should it type?
var $input = document.getElementById("someInput");

function writeLetter() {
    var currentText = $input.value;
    var currentLetter = text.charAt(currentLetterCount);
    currentLetterCount++;
    $input.value = currentText + currentLetter;
    if(currentLetterCount == charCount)
        clearInterval(timerId);
}

var timerId = setInterval(writeLetter, speed);
```

I'm basically looking to convert that into Java. Please help, many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Java Version of Above code:

```
Class LetterDisplay(){

public String text = "The quick fox jumped over the lazy dog.";
public int charCount = text.length;
public int currentLetterCount = 0;
public int speed = 100; // How fast should it type?   
TextView textarea = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv); 


public static void main(String[] args){

LetterDisplay mainObj = new LetterDisplay();

Runnable r = new MyThread(mainObj);
new Thread(r).start();


}

public class MyThread implements Runnable {

   public MyThread(Object parameter) {
       // store parameter for later user
   }

   public void run() {


     try {
      doRun();
    } finally {
      notifyListeners();
    }
    public doRun(){
    String currentText = textarea.getText();
    char currentLetter = text.charAt(currentLetterCount);
    currentLetterCount++;
    textarea.setText(currentText + currentLetter);
    if(currentLetterCount == charCount)
        Thread.stop(); // this is Evil way to Stop a Thread
  }
try{ Thread.Sleep(speed); } catch(Exception e){}
    }
   }
}
```

i hopes this help...

Comment: Thanks, now would I input this into my MainActivity.java Java Class or the activity_main.xml resource file? And I would have to replace string names with my own, right?

Comment: Did you intend to use the speed int somewhere?